# Comparar primeiros caracteres de duas colunas distintas em excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Existe alguma função no excel que me permita comparar os primeiros n caracteres de texto que eu quiser?

```
Por exemplo

Tenho a palavra Joaquim e Joana, comparo por "Joa" e ele me retorna verdadeiro ou falso.
```

Comment: Você pode usar a função `=EXT.TEXTO()`, para extrair a quantidade de caracteres de uma string e posteriormente usar a função `=EXATO()` para comparar duas strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Fórmula utilizada:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Resultado obtido:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Muito obrigado!!!